# Rotating image (center fix). Return angle

Tags: iphone, xcode, image

I am a newbie and am facing this problem...

I need to rotate a round picture (the center is fixed) in increments of 6 degrees image (where the freedom of rotation is 0 to 180 degrees) and my application should return the angle by which the image is rotated...

It would be great if someone could give me atleast an hint on how to start...

Thanks in advance for any (literally) response!

Answer (score 1):

You can rotate an UIImageView by using CGAffineTransform. To start you can have a look at the following line of code...

// define basic constant/macros

```
#define DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(angle) (angle / 180.0 * M_PI)
```

// method to rotate

```
-(void) rotateImage:(UIImageView *) imageView degrees:(CGFloat) degrees<br/>
{
  CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(degrees));
   imageView.transform = transform;
}
```

// add the image

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"round.png"];
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
imageView.frame = CGRectMake(INITIAL_X, INITIAL_Y, image.size.width, image.size.height);
[parentView addSubview:imageView];
```

// call method to rotate image whenever you wanna do so...
// here we call it to rotate 6 degree for an example at initial stage..

```
[self rotateImage:imageView degrees:6];
[imageView release];
```

Hope this will help you.